# 2013 honda crv won't start, used to crank now won't even crank

Tags: honda, starting, crv

I have a 2013 Honda CR-V and yesterday it didn't start and then i used another car to jump start and drove it for an hour to local stores (without turning off the engine).

This morning it won't start again, tried afternoon no luck. At least it was making the crank sound.

In evening i tried to jump start the car and heard a motor kind of sound even without the key in the vehicle with the side lights (front/back) on. After removing the circuit the sound/lights went away. Now even the crank would not work.Even there is no lights on dashboard(nothing shows up).The only thing which is working is the Hazard light and the brake light.

Could this be because the battery is so drained that it can't even show the dashboard lights?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It very well could be the battery. Use a digital multimeter on the battery and see what it's reading. If it's below 11vdc, it's too low. You can try to put a battery charger on it for a while to see if it will recover. If the battery it's the original battery in the car, consider changing it straight out. Also check for corrosion on the battery terminals. Clean if necessary.

Comment: Thank you Paulster2 for the suggestion.The battery is the original battery. I already checked the battery terminals they are clean. I got worried because when i tried to jump start this evening as soon as i connected the negative terminal a sound like a motor running came from somewhere under the hood. The side lights came on (dim though). I finally disconnected the circuit and then tried to jump start again without any luck. How are the hazard light and brake light powered (is it not through the battery). I am planning to try one more time tomorrow before getting it towed to a mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly sounds like a battery issue.  The "jump start" success is a key fact.

Modern vehicle clusters "dashboards" are often electronic in nature, requiring a minimum voltage to work at all.  The brake and hazard lights are simply bulb filaments, and might work to some degree at a much lower voltage.

Even if you are able to charge the battery back to the point where it will start the vehicle, the battery may have suffered damage (a reduction in capacity) due to the lower voltage.  Chemical changes start to occur in a battery once they drop below 12 volts, and no amount of charging will repair that.  What may suffice in the summer may leave you stranded in the winter.

Four to five years is a reasonable average expected lifespan of an OEM "original" battery.

Comment: Thank you SteveRacer for your answer. The only think which worried me this evening was a motor running kind of sound from under the hood and the side lights front and back came on(dim though) and I thought I did something wrong while jump starting. It was definitely not any shower of Spark as i read in other posts here. Just want to understand what could have triggered that running motor kind of sound with the side lights on. I am hoping to at least able to start it tomorrow and then got to a mechanic to get the battery changed.

Comment: I would not be too concerned.  That motor noise is either a fuel pump or the ABS hydraulic pump, which probably do not have enough voltage and are running for an abnormally long period to build pressure -- something that happens all the time, but you normally would not notice if the battery was in good shape and the vehicle starts right away.